# « » Symbol not displayed correctly LYX

Tags: lyx

I try to include this symbol « »in my LYX document but when i run my code , it's displayed as a black square.
Can some one help me please.

Comment: can you post an example file please?

Comment: even though you solved the problem, I would still be interested in an example file. It's possible this is a bug in LyX (maybe it should load the lmodern package automatically when you insert that character) that we need to fix.

Comment: sorry for the delay,  you mean i send you the input file ?

Comment: You can post it here. A .lyx file is just a text file so you can open it in a text editor and copy/paste it here. Or you can send it to lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org . Or you can post it on http://www.lyx.org/trac . Either of those options is fine. It should be a small file (see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample).

Comment: yeah it's done , I send my file to lyx email

Comment: Thanks for doing that. We'll check it out and see if we can improve things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this should do it

> \usepackage{lmodern}

Comment: ...where? When I create a minimal document and just include `«»` I don't seem to have any problems...

Comment: It's solved by adding package lmodern